# Regular expression route constraint for a resource route

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel offers the possibility to add regular expression constraint to a route like this:

```
Route::get('user/{name}', function($name)
{
    //
})
->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

it is also possible to create multiple routes for a resource:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

I want to add regular expression constraint only to the route `GET /photo/{id}`

is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you can't but you may mimic that using something like this (route filtering):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('checkParam', array('only' => array('getEdit', 'postUpdate')));
}
```

This is an example of route filtering using the constructor and here I've filtering only two methods (you may use `except` or nothing at all) and declared the filter in `filters.php` file as given below:

```
Route::filter('checkParam', function($route, $request){
    // one is the default name for the first parameter
    $param1 = $route->parameter('one');
    if(!preg_match('/\d/', $param1)) {
        App::abort(404);
        // Or this one
        throw new Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
    }
});
```

Here, I'm checking the first parameter manually (`parameters` method returns an array of all parameters passed to the route) and if it's not a digit then throwing `NotFoundHttpException` exception.

You may also catch the exception by registering a handler like this:

```
App::missing(function($exception){
    // show a user friendly message or whatever...
});
```

Comment: How can we set same feature in laravel 5? any ideas?

Comment: Filters are replaced with Middleware in version - 5x.

Answer (score 12):

In Laravel 5 resourceful route parameters [can be named](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) like this:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['parameters' => [
   'user' => 'id'
]]);
```

This can be combined with [route patterns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-global-constraints):

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
```

So you can easily define a single global constraint for route parameters and use if for all of your resourceful routes.

Answer (score 1):

In your `RouteServiceProvider` `boot()` method, just reference the parameter name using `Route::pattern('parameter', 'regex')`. Note: the parameter name is the *singular* (if path is plural) of the path.

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::pattern('photo', '[0-9]+');

    parent::boot();
}
```

This would work for both:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

and

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

Note: if you typehint your parameter to the model, this is not necessary. For example:

```
public function show(Photo $photo)
{
    //
}
```

Now, if a non-matching parameter is passed, a `404 | Not Found` will be returned. But if you are using `Route::fallback()` to handle unmatched routes, you should keep `Route::pattern('parameter', 'regex')`.

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite `IlluminateFoundation\Exceptions\Handler` :

```
if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
            if (str_contains($exception->getMessage(), "Invalid text representation:")) {
                $requestId = $exception->getBindings()[0] ?? "";
                App::abort(404);
               // Or this one
               throw new Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
            } else {
               throw $exception;
            }
        }
```