# How can I use "where" in a Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

If I have the next route:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', function($id) {
    return View::make(users.profile, array('id' => $id));
})->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));`
```

How could I do the same in a Restful controller?

```
Route::controller('/user', 'UserController');
```

My UserController:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getProfile($id) {
        return View::make('users.profile', array('id' => $id));
    }
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` doesn't appear to work when chained onto a `Route::controller` call, but you can achieve the same functionality with the `Route::pattern` declaration. So, for example, this code for a Route::controller (called "implicit routing") would work, limiting `id` to numeric:

```
Route::pattern('id', '\d+');
Route::controller('/user/{id}', 'UserController');
```

Then, in UserController, the `getIndex` method would be called from a GET request:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {
    public function getIndex($id) {
        return View::make('users.profile', array('id' => $id));
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this only works for the index method, i.e. for calls to `http:://example.com/user/99`. If you want to use other controller methods using "implicit routing", for example `http:://example.com/user/profile/99` and the controller method `getProfile($id)`, you need to declare your route *without* the `{id}` parameter, like so:

```
Route::controller('/user', 'UserController');
```

...in which case, you aren't able to use `->where` or `Route::pattern` to constrain the `{id}`, since there is no `{id}` parameter to constrain.

In the end, you're better off going with "explicit routing," as you do at the beginning of your answer, or using RESTful Resource Controllers ([see the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)) and specifying your route as:

`Route::resource('user', 'UserController');`.

If you subscribe to Laracasts, Jeffrey Way has a great, clear tutorial about some of the perils of "implicit routing" [here](https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-no-to-implicit-routing).

Comment: If I use resource controller for exanple:

`Route::resource("user", "UserController", array("only", array("index","show")));`

And I set the next path:

`http://domain.com/user/abc`

Laravel validate that isn't a valid parameter?

Comment: Right, `Route::resource` won't allow you to constrain the `id` parameter using `Route::pattern` (or `Route::group`, for that matter) since there's no explicit `id` parameter to constrain. I think you have two options: 1) use `Route::resource` or `Route::controller`, but explicitly define the routes you want to constrain (like `Route::get('/user/{id}...'` *before* the `Route::controller`; or (2) user a before filter, as detailed in [Regular expression route constraint for a resource route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622629/regular-expression-route-constraint-for-a-resource-route).

Answer (score 0):

To make sure about the `methods` and `URL` run the `php artisan routes` from your terminal so you'll get the list of all routes you have access to with their `URL`. In this case for the following `route` and `controller` you may find a `URL` like `user/profile/10`

```
// Route
Route::controller('/user', 'UserController');

// Controller
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getProfile($id) {

        return View::make('users.profile', array('id' => $id));
    }

}
```

So use `http://domain.com/user/profile/10`, here `10` will be passed to the `$id` variable in your `profile` method. Also remember that, in `RESTfull` controller each method should be prefixed with the `HTTP` verb they responds to so in this case this method will respond to a `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do it you want to wrap your `Route::controller` statements in a group and apply `where` pattern for the group, since setting it globally might not be accurate for other routes:

```
Route::group('where' => ['id' => '\d+'], function () {

   Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
   // other restful controller definitions with this pattern go here

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll prove it.